# Is it possible to upload a Android app on a store for testing purposes only (before the actual release)?

Tags: android, testing, google-play

Is it possible to upload an Android app on a Android play store for testing purposes only (before the actual release) so that :

- The developers can test the publication process under real conditions.
- The testers can download the app for free and test it before it is available to the public (possibly with a password).
- The public at large does not see this test version of the app.

(Basically it’s like asking an editor for a proof exemplar, before the actual publication of a book)

This is not the same as « How to publish a beta version on Google Play ? », since a beta version is in theory accessible to all users an not to a limited (chosen, specific) list of testers.

Comment: Yeah, I concur, the answers there don't describe how to run a Play Store private test.  Voting to leave open.

Comment: The answer provided in the linked thread is very outdated and doesn't match the question here. This questions is explicitly about a "dry-run" release process. Not about sharing an APK file through dropbox or other solutions. Play Store uploads are required to test e.g.: Instant Apps, delivery of dynamic features, app bundles in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

I assume you are talking about the Google Play Store specifically, since it's the biggest and most official app store for android.

Google Play Store offers various test tracks:

- Internal test: For up to 100 testers, invitation only
- Closed test: Same as internal, just for more users
- Open Test: Anyone can join

In all test tracks, users can only leave feedback instead of reviews and app ratings.
You can create multiple different tests and versions at the same time and invite different users. For example if you want to test features only in certain regions.

Additionally, there is internal app sharing which allows you to quickly share app bundles or APKs via a link through Google Play Store. This is for example usefull for CI / CD where each build is uploaded to internal app sharing. This is also currently the only solution for this usecase which supports Android App Bundles. Other solutions like Microsoft Appcenter only allow APK uploads.

### Imporant info before you upload

Once you upload an APK or app bundle for the first time, certain parameters will be set and become unchangable in the specific play store entry:

- app package name
- app signing key

So once you upload an app in either of the test tracks, without even releasing it, you can not change the app's package name or upload it with a different signing key. A different package name will require a new play store entry.

The signing key can only be changed when the original key is still present (there is a roll-over process for that, but you need the original signing key for that!). So make sure you back up the signing key and don't use the default debug signing key for test uploads.

Further info:

- [Set up an open, closed, or internal test](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334)
- [Share app bundles and APKs internally](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you very much, that answers my question perfectly!